# Is it really not possible to have two multi-record custom fieldsets in one profile?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, multi-record

I'm trying to set up a form for contacts to update their own data via our Joomla frontend.  However, I ran into an unexpected problem when I tried to add a second multi-record custom fieldset to a profile:

"You cannot configure multi-record custom fields belonging to different custom sets in one profile"

Does this mean I have to create TWO profile edit forms if I want my users to be able to update all their data via the frontend?  I'd really prefer all the frontend data entry for the user in one form, not have to break it up.  Is there any other way around this?

System deets:  Joomla 3.9.26, CiviCRM 5.37.1

Comment: can you confirm what entity eg Contact, Individual, Contribution etc these fieldsets are being used on

Comment: and/or set up a really simple example on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org so you can compare and others can take a look

Comment: This is a custom contact type, a subtype of Organization.  I'll set up something on the demo and post here when completed.

Comment: So of course I'm not getting this error on the demo :-(  I've set up two multi-record custom fieldsets (Multi-Record Fieldsets 1 and 2) for the Organization-Team contact type, and successfully created a profile "Edit Multi Record Fieldsets" with all fields from custom fieldsets included.

Comment: In the process now of trying to figure out what's different between demo setup and mine.  Differences I already am aware of:  
Demo = Drupal, My System =Joomla
Demo version=5.39.alpha1, My version=5.37.1

Comment: I'm stumped.  I've found the error in /CRM/UF/Form/Field.php line 785, and indeed there's a check "if profile already has a different multi-record custom set field configured".  So I don't know why it's actually working in the demo?

Comment: it may not be a great workaround but iirc we have 'daisy-chained' profiles together in the past, so it seems like a multi-page form - might be a thought?

Comment: Interesting suggestion petednz -- how exactly would that be done?

Comment: i may have misspoken - i checked what we have done previously and it was to ensure that if someone used a checksum to do a renewal, they could then click through to a second profile after submitting the form, and 'keep the session open'. i don't see why a similar approach could not be done from one Profile to another.

Comment: Hmm ok, sounds good, but not sure if I'm following.  I don't understand the mechanics of "clicking through and keeping the session open". Is this just customizing one profile to include a link to the second?  But how does the data submission work?

Comment: when you set up a Profile you can specify where people go when they submit it. therefore you should be able to set Profile A to redirect to Profile B on submission. I expect this will work 'as is' for logged in users. problem is if you send some to Profile A via a link with a checksum, the checksum will 'expire' before they get to Profile B, hence they would be submitting that form as 'anonymous'. assuming that is not acceptable, you would need a customisation so the the 'session' that is opened on Profile A is extended to cover Profile B. hth

Comment: Ah ok, so this would be simple forwarding to a separate profile on submission.  In this case Checksums aren't needed, as we don't use personalized links for these profile forms.  Not the prettiest workaround, but should do the job.

Thanks so much for your help and patience!  Do you want to post this as an answer so I can award you the bounty points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a Profile as you can specify where people go when they submit it.

therefore you should be able to set Profile A to redirect to Profile B on submission.

I expect this will work 'as is' for logged in users.

There would be a problem if you send someone to Profile A via a link with a checksum as the checksum will 'expire' before they get to Profile B, hence they would be submitting that form as 'anonymous'. if that daisy-chaining the profiles is a requirement, you would need a customisation so the the 'session' that is opened on Profile A is extended to cover Profile B